# DialogFlow Telephony Gateway country code

Tags: dialogflow-es

How do I change the country code in DialogFlow Telephony Gateway? The only option is US. I would like a Canadian #. So I do not have to pay long distance charges.

Answer (score 0):

[The Telephony Gateway documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/telephony) suggests there should be a dropdown menu that lets you chose your country code.

Under the subheading 'Set up a telephony gateway', step 2, 'Configure Phone Gateway', substep b, 'Select the country code for the telephone number.', I would expect an option to select from a list of countries that support Telephony Gateway.

Can you add a screenshot of what you see when you click that dropdown menu?

Comment: The drop down menu contains only the US

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Dialogflow Phone Gateway BETA only supports telephone numbers from the US. You can follow up on new supported countries on the [languages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/language) section of the documentation under the column "Telephony".